# Communication between React Native and Java native module

Tags: java, android, react-native, promise

Currently I have a file uploader module written in Java. I'm trying to use promise, but in this case I can send data only once, when the operation finished. My code currently:

```
if (FileType.MESH_OBJ.equalsName(filename)) {
  uploadHandler = new UploadFileTask() {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
      objReady = true;
      Log.d(appName, "Upload done: object");
      if (objReady == true && imgReady == true && mtlReady == true && jpegReady == true) {
        promise.resolve("finish");
      }
    }
  };
} else if (FileType.PREVIEW_IMAGE.equalsName(filename)) {
  uploadHandler = new UploadFileTask() {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
      imgReady = true;
      Log.d(appName, "Upload done: image");
      if (objReady == true && imgReady == true && mtlReady == true && jpegReady == true) {
        promise.resolve("finish");
      }
    }
  };
}
```

How you see in every case I have to check everything is ready. It would be good the following somehow: 
Everytime when something uploaded send a response to the React Native. On the JS side I handle it with a `.then()` as follow:

```
FileHandler.upload(...).then(...)
```

Is there any solution for something this or only the requst-response solution existed?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) for creating a native Java module.

Basically you will define the module on the Java side like this:

```
public class FileHandler extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "FileHandler";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void upload(String fileName, Promise promise) {
    if (FileType.MESH_OBJ.equalsName(filename)) {
      uploadHandler = new UploadFileTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
          objReady = true;
          Log.d(appName, "Upload done: object");
          if (objReady == true && imgReady == true && mtlReady == true && jpegReady == true) {
            promise.resolve("finish");
          }
        }
      };
    } else if (FileType.PREVIEW_IMAGE.equalsName(filename)) {
      uploadHandler = new UploadFileTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
          imgReady = true;
          Log.d(appName, "Upload done: image");
          if (objReady == true && imgReady == true && mtlReady == true && jpegReady == true) {
            promise.resolve("finish");
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

And call it on the JavaScript side:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
NativeModules.FileHandler.upload(...).then(...)
```

Don't forget to [register the module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#register-the-module).

Comment: Did you copy&paste my code? It is an answer how to communicate between native and react native code, but not for my problem. Please read the post. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem.